# Rails SHOW FIELDS FROM doesn't work after create_table

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails-4

I added some fields to a table, but when I type SHOW FIELDS FROM users; in `mysql` from UNIX, it only shows the ID and `timestamp` field.

Basically, it is not acknowledging I created a table with the fields below. I have included code from my CreateUsers Active::Migration and further below what appears in mysql where it does not show the fields after I have added them. Thanks to anyone who can help.

My rails create table code:

```
def up
    create_table :users do |t|
    t.string "first_name", :limit => 25
    t.string "last_name", :limit => 50
    t.string "email", :default => "", :null => false
    t.string "password", :limit => 40

    #t.datetime "created_at"
    #t.datetime "updated_at" 
    t.timestamps 
  end
end

def down
    drop_table :users
  end

end
```

My msql failed result:

```
mysql> SHOW FIELDS FROM users;
+------------+----------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field      | Type     | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+------------+----------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id         | int(11)  | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| created_at | datetime | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| updated_at | datetime | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+------------+----------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
3 rows in set (0.01 sec)

mysql>
```

Comment: Your question title is misleading: SHOW FIELDS query works perfectly here. The problem is elsewhere.

Comment: Please run the migration with --trace option and post the output here ($ rake db:migrate --trace)

Comment: I'm curious if you added the fields to the create table *after* you'd already run the migration?